# How to test Angular JS directive with file upload and onchange event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, directive

I am about to give up on this. I have tried every which way to access the directive scope in a test.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('cmsModuleApp')
  .directive('fileUpload', function () {
    return {
      scope: {},  
      template: '<input type="file" >',
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: function fileUploadCtrl (scope) {
         //also tried scope.uploadFile here... 
         this.uploadFile = function (files) {console.log("please work...")};
      },
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, Ctrl) {
          element.uploadFile = function (files) {console.log("pleaseeeee")};
      }
    };
  });
```

**test:**:

```
'use strict';

describe('Directive: fileUpload', function () {

  beforeEach(module('cmsModuleApp'));

  var element;
  var scope;
  var files;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
  }));

  it('should call a file upload method onchange event', inject(function ($compile) {

    element = angular.element('<file-upload></file-upload>');
    element = $compile(element)(scope);

    //tried moving this around thinking maybe it had to render or update
    scope.$digest();

    //Im loggin the element's scope to explore the object a bit
    console.log(element.scope()); 

    spyOn(element.scope(), 'uploadFile') 
    element.triggerHandler('onchange');

    expect(element.scope().uploadFile()).toHaveBeenCalled();

  }));
});
```

What I am trying to test is that when this file input changes (is clicked and loaded up with files) it will execute the `uploadFile()` method on the directive's scope. Once I get this working I was going to implement an `$http` service.

However, the method does not exist or is undefined.. No matter what I seem to try.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to modify your test file like this?

I moved the variables declaration into the `describe` and the test initilization into the `beforeEach`. Then I created a spy on `scope.uploadFile`.

**fileUpload_test** :

```
'use strict';

describe('Directive: fileUpload', function () {
  var element;
  var scope;
  var files;

  beforeEach(module('cmsModuleApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = angular.element('<file-upload></file-upload>');
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
  }));

  afterEach(function() {
    scope.$destroy();
  });

  it('should call a file upload method onchange event', function() {
    scope.uploadFile = jasmine.createSpy();

    element.triggerHandler('change');

    expect(scope.uploadFile).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for giving it a shot, but it still wont recognize fileUpload as a function. I am not entirely sure I understand directive scope. I am reading up all the docs I can find now. I will post a solution if I find one.

Comment: @Davey It think it would work if you used scope.uploadFile instead of this.uploadFile (controller declaration of the directive) or element.uploadFile (in the link function). The scope is accessible to the test, so you need to expose your function in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be that you are using an isolate scope `scope: {}`. Here's an example of how I did a similar task:

```
describe('File Input Directive', function() {
  var scope, element, isolateScope;

  beforeEach(function() {
    bard.appModule('appName');
    bard.inject(this, '$compile', '$rootScope');
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    var html = '<form><my-file-input /></form>';
    var form = angular.element(html);
    element = form.find('my-file-input');
    var formElement = $compile(form)(scope);
    scope.$digest();

    isolateScope = element.isolateScope();
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    scope.$destroy();
  });

  bard.verifyNoOutstandingHttpRequests();

  describe('selectFile', function() {
    it('triggers a click on the file input', function() {
      var fileInput = $(element).find('.none')[0];
      var mockClick = sinon.spy(fileInput, 'click');

      isolateScope.selectFile();
      scope.$digest();

      expect(mockClick).calledOnce;
    });
  });
```

You can ignore all of the bard references - it's a helper library, which reduces some boilerplate. The important parts are creating the `isolateScope` in the `beforeEach` and referencing the directive's method (in this case, selectFile) on the `isolateScope` in the test itself. Also, notice the `scope.$digest()` after calling the method. Hope it helps!